# How to draw a solid circle with cocos2d for iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, geometry

Is it possible to draw a filled circle with cocos2d ?
An outlined circle can be done using the drawCircle() function, but is there a way to fill it in a certain color? Perhaps by using pure OpenGL?

Answer (score 21):

In DrawingPrimitives.m, change this in drawCricle:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, segs+additionalSegment);
```

to:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, segs+additionalSegment);
```

You can read more about opengl primitives here:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=461848

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight modification of ccDrawCircle() that lets you draw any slice of a circle. Stick this in CCDrawingPrimitives.m and also add the method header information to CCDrawingPrimitives.h:

Parameters: `a`: starting angle in radians, `d`: delta or change in angle in radians (use `2*M_PI` for a complete circle)

Changes are commented

```
void ccDrawFilledCircle( CGPoint center, float r, float a, float d, NSUInteger totalSegs)
{
    int additionalSegment = 2;

    const float coef = 2.0f * (float)M_PI/totalSegs;

    NSUInteger segs = d / coef;
    segs++; //Rather draw over than not draw enough

    if (d == 0) return;

    GLfloat *vertices = calloc( sizeof(GLfloat)*2*(segs+2), 1);
    if( ! vertices )
        return;

    for(NSUInteger i=0;i<=segs;i++)
    {
        float rads = i*coef;
        GLfloat j = r * cosf(rads + a) + center.x;
        GLfloat k = r * sinf(rads + a) + center.y;

        //Leave first 2 spots for origin
        vertices[2+ i*2] = j * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
        vertices[2+ i*2+1] =k * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    }
    //Put origin vertices into first 2 spots
    vertices[0] = center.x * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    vertices[1] = center.y * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();

    // Default GL states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Needed states: GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 
    // Unneeded states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY   
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    //Change to fan
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, segs+additionalSegment);

    // restore default state
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

    free( vertices );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into:

- CGContextAddArc
- CGContextFillPath

These will allow you to fill a circle without needing OpenGL

Answer (score 1):

I also wonder this, but haven't really accomplished doing it. I tried using CGContext stuff that Grouchal tipped above, but I can't get it to draw anything on the screen. This is what I've tried:

```
-(void) draw
{
    [self makestuff:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
}

-(void)makestuff:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Drawing lines with a white stroke color
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    // Draw a single line from left to right
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 30.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 30.0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // Draw a connected sequence of line segments
    CGPoint addLines[] =
    {
        CGPointMake(10.0, 90.0),
        CGPointMake(70.0, 60.0),
        CGPointMake(130.0, 90.0),
        CGPointMake(190.0, 60.0),
        CGPointMake(250.0, 90.0),
        CGPointMake(310.0, 60.0),
    };
    // Bulk call to add lines to the current path.
    // Equivalent to MoveToPoint(points[0]); for(i=1; i<count; ++i) AddLineToPoint(points[i]);
    CGContextAddLines(context, addLines, sizeof(addLines)/sizeof(addLines[0]));
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // Draw a series of line segments. Each pair of points is a segment
    CGPoint strokeSegments[] =
    {
        CGPointMake(10.0, 150.0),
        CGPointMake(70.0, 120.0),
        CGPointMake(130.0, 150.0),
        CGPointMake(190.0, 120.0),
        CGPointMake(250.0, 150.0),
        CGPointMake(310.0, 120.0),
    };
    // Bulk call to stroke a sequence of line segments.
    // Equivalent to for(i=0; i<count; i+=2) { MoveToPoint(point[i]); AddLineToPoint(point[i+1]); StrokePath(); }
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(context, strokeSegments, sizeof(strokeSegments)/sizeof(strokeSegments[0]));
}
```

These methods are defined in a cocos node class, and the makestuff method I borrowed from a code example...

NOTE:
I'm trying to draw any shape or path and fill it. I know that the code above only draws lines, but I didn't wanna continue until I got it working.

EDIT:
This is probably a crappy solution, but I think this would at least *work*.

Each CocosNode has a texture (Texture2D *). Texture2D class can be initialized from an UIImage. UIImage can be initialized from a CGImageRef. It is possible to create a CGImageRef context for the quartz lib.

So, what you would do is:

1. Create the CGImageRef context for quartz
2. Draw into this image with quartz
3. Initialize an UIImage with this CGImageRef
4. Make a Texture2D that is initialized with that image
5. Set the texture of a CocosNode to that Texture2D instance

Question is if this would be fast enough to do. I would prefer if you could sort of get a CGImageRef from the CocosNode directly and draw into it instead of going through all these steps, but I haven't found a way to do that yet (and I'm kind of a noob at this so it's hard to actually get somewhere at all).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new function in cocos2d `CCDrawingPrimitives` called `ccDrawSolidCircle(CGPoint center, float r, NSUInteger segs)`. For those looking at this now, use this method instead, then you don't have to mess with the cocos2d code, just import `CCDrawingPrimitives.h`

Answer (score -1):

I used this way below.

```
glLineWidth(2);
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
  ccDrawCircle( ccp(s.width/2,  s.height/2), i,0, 50, NO);
}
```

I made multiple circle with for loop and looks like a filled circle.